# Pocket door variation

Tags: doors

Remodeling the bathroom. I want to put in a pocket door, centered, in a 60" opening.  Is there a split door product available, that will work similar in principle to draw drapes?

To put the door in as planned, right now, the door opening is in the corner.  I don't like it: at all. The contractor did not want to move electrical wiring to make room for the door on the side of  'opening' that had room to make the pocket door go where I wanted it.

Comment: Since I don't much about the layout, there is an electrical code that has to be followed.  Any wall over 2 feet must have a receptacle (210.52A).  I  don't know how this affects or counts with the hollowness of the pocket door.  Maybe this is why the electrician didn't move it.  The wall in my house that has the pocket doors are various and none of them have receptacles.  One 45", all pocket door.  Also, do yourself a favor and don't buy cheap hardware.  Get the ones that you have to slide the rollers in through the end and designed not to pop out when a kid starts playing with it.

Comment: @lqlarry the 2 foot rule does not apply to bath rooms, or hallways, so that may not be the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a 'split door' but rather just two narrow pocket doors. A pocket door is just a regular door hung on a rail system. Buy two narrow doors, two pocket door rail systems, and you should be good to go.